# How to add a progress bar column inside the asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, progress-bar, radgrid

I have asp.net grid for which i have a column called status in each of the gridcolumn for status i want to place a progress bar which gives the status. please can give me some implementation idea on this.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2008/03/14/free-progress-bar-for-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to put progress bar there? Is each row in grid has a status (such as % complete) that is keep changing? Is your grid keep refreshing periodically?

Said all that, I will probably go with [jquery UI progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/). Its a client side plug-in so you can easily initialize values at server side and then update them on client side if your status is changing dynamically by making AJAX calls to get the status from server.

Comment: Ya status column in the grid gets refreshed very frequently, and i  want to show the dynamic status to users with some pictorial representation so i am planning to use progress bar in each of the column