# ProgressBar show in GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

In `Gridview` cell, I have to show `ProgressBar` in ASP.NET.

I am using async event in ASP.NET 4.0

Could you guide me to find the solution for it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657286/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-column-inside-the-asp-net-gridview

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean from the client side ajax.  If not, can you elaborate?  If you are using a simple update panel you can just drop a Update Progress control on the page and put whatever you want to display as "progress" in the ProgressTemplate.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Loading...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```